# ReactMeteorData Class extends value undefined is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am new to Meteor 1.7 i was following the tutorial for the simple-todos app. But after i added the react-meteor-data package it broke my app. I keep getthing the following the error.

```
/Users/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_3.w8zcf.uowlh++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at ReactMeteorData.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx:162:46)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
    at createContainer.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx:1:254)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
    at react-meteor-data.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/react-meteor-data.jsx:1:139)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
    at /Users/userName/Sites/drupalvm/sites/Meteor-test-app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-meteor-data.js:331:15
    at /Users/userName/Sites/drupalvm/sites/Meteor-test-app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-meteor-data.js:338:3
    at /Users/userName/Sites/drupalvm/sites/Meteor-test-app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

If anyone could help me out on what i am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error means that React was imported incorrectly in the file where `withTracker` is imported.

Make sure that the import line looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up restarting my app and it started working again.